# mainframe - DATA SET SHECICS.ZEUSBANK.TXNOFFLD NOT FOUND

Tags: dataset, mainframe, jcl, dfsort

I have a sequential dataset has the form of this

```
0000000520161103152815SHE0009 P1234561234567898765411112222        120AA
```

The last 2 bytes (position 71 and 72) are separate CH of either AA, AB, BA or blank. I'm trying to sort this input and create a report of sections AA, AB, BA and ignore the record that doesn't have AA, AB or BA. Each row of each section shows the teller name (SHE0009 above, position 23), and the payment (120 above, 11 bytes before AA, position 60). The final line of each section sum all the payments from that section.

[image]

Here's my code

```
 //SHE0008 JOB                                                          
 //SORTSTEP EXEC PGM=SORT                                               
 //SYSOUT   DD SYSOUT=*                                                 
 //SYSPRINT DD SYSOUT=*                                                 
 //SORTIN   DD DSN='SHECISC.ZEUSBANK.TXNOFFLD',DISP=SHR                 
 //SORTOUT  DD DSN=SHE0008.TESTT,                                       
 //          DISP=(NEW,CATLG,DELETE),SPACE=(CYL,(10,5),RLSE)            
 //SYSIN  DD *                                                          
   SORT FIELDS=(71,1,CH,A,72,1,CH.A)                                    
   INREC BUILD=(71,1,72,1,23,8,60,11,BI,TO=ZD,LENGTH=11)                
   OUTFIL REMOVECC,                                                     
          SECTIONS=(1,1,2,1                                             
          HEADER3=(1:C'PAYMENTS BY TELLER',/,X,/,                       
                   1:C'TRANSFER TYPE:    ',1,1,2,1,/,X,/,               
                   1:C'TELLER',10:C'PAYMENT',/,                         
                   1:C'------',10:C'-------'),                          
          TRAILER3=(X,/,                                                
     1:C'BRANCH TOTAL: ',16:TOT=(11,11,BI,EDIT=(SIIIITTT),SIGNS=(,-)))),
          TRAILER1=(X,/,1:C'GRAND TOTAL: ',TOT=(11,11,BI,               
                         EDIT=(SIIIITTT),SIGNS=(,-))),                  
         OUTREC=(1:7,4,CH,LENGTH=7,10:11,4,BI,EDIT=(SIIIITTT),          
                         SIGNS=(,-))                                    
 /*
```

I'm getting error `SORTIN - DATA SET SHECISC.ZEUSBANK.TXNOFFLD NOT FOUNDI
- STEP WAS NOT EXECUTED.` Can anyone see why my dataset cannot be found and if possible is this the code that makes my desired result. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file name is `SHECICS.ZEUSBANK.TXNOFFLD` you wrote `SHECISC.ZEUSBANK.TXNOFFLD`.

You misspelt the first part "SHECICS" that could be the problem.

Comment: Oh, that helps. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the quotes around the dataset name.

i.e. change

```
//SORTIN   DD DSN='SHECISC.ZEUSBANK.TXNOFFLD',DISP=SHR
```

to

```
//SORTIN   DD DSN=SHECISC.ZEUSBANK.TXNOFFLD,DISP=SHR
```

The reasoning being :-

> If quotation marks delimit a data set name in a JCL DD statement, JCL
>   processing cannot perform syntax checking on the statement, and SMS
>   rejects the input based on its parsing of the data set name. SMS does
>   not allow the name to be catalogued because quoted data sets cannot be
>   SMS managed.

SMS being System Managed Storage, although I believe that the result would have been the same in pre-SMS times. If I recall correctly I also had the odd tape created with `DSN='         '`, (a number of spaces) which would fool quite a few people if they tried to read the tape i.e. quotes allowed you to use con-conformant dataset names.

The following my be of interest:-

[Data Set Names](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.1.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r1.idad400/name.htm)

[Character sets - Table 2. Special Characters Used in Syntax](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.1.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r1.ieab600/charseh.htm)

Comment: I tried either way, with and without quote, the dataset is still not found. But if I find it in 3.4 section, it is still there.

Comment: When I changed to `DD SYSOUT=*                                     
 DD DSN=SHECISC.ZEUSBANK.TXNOFFLD,DISP=(MOD,CATLG)`. It says `DEFINE - RESOURCE NOT PROTECTED and ALLOCATION FAILED DUE TO DATA FACILITY SYSTEM`. How can I fix that?

Comment: The best way to fix it is to consider what you missed when you pasted the two messages. i.e. the **`ICH408I`** and the **`IEF344I`**. Learning to make use of them will fix 99% of all problems you encounter via what's know as **RTFM**.  For the first you should find `This error occurs when RACF® detects an unauthorized attempt to define a RACF-protected resource.` the **System Action** is more telling, so look at that. **`etc`** **(Note this is intended to help you, please see it as such)**